# Keep iPhone rotation in landscape?

Tags: iphone, xcode, rotation

I'm making an app that is only in landscape mode but I've found that when I rotate the device, the app auto-rotates to that orientation. I specified in the project summary that I wanted only "Landscape Left" and then in each view controller I put

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
 {
 return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft; 
 }
```

Although the app starts in landscape when I click rotate right or left, the simulator goes into portrait as it should but then the app auto-rotates as well. How can I get the app to stay in landscape even when the device is rotated?

Comment: Does it do it on a device too? It could be something goofy with the simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what you did,
Instead of your `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` function, use the following

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks! This worked! Just out of curiosity, is there a way to make it so that it will support left and right orientation but just not portrait or portrait upside-down?

Comment: each orientation you want to support will be added in the return, for example return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight); will support right and left landscape

Comment: @user1242108 See the second example in my answer for exactly how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstood what the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` is for. It is **not** asking you *"What orientations do you support?"*, it **is** asking you *"Do you support this interface orientation?"*. So your answer should be either `YES` or `NO`.

It will ask you this each time before it decides to change orientation, so you can change your mind and sometimes support it, sometimes not (if you really want).

For example, to support all orientations:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

...to support only landscape orientations:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) ||
        (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));
}
```

...to support only landscape-left (as you want):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your info.plist, you need to set the key for `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations`, As seen below.:

[image]

This limit's my app to run only in Landscape mode, in addition to your `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method. If you're supporting Landscape Left/Right. Your method should look like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return  (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```