# i designed my nib in land scape mode, but in simulator it is showing in portrait mode?

Tags: ios, ipad

i designed my nib in land scape mode with buttons and images, but in simulator it is showing in landscape mode but the button and images are not as it looks on the nib, they appear to be on right hand side instead of on top? any pointers please. 
nib image[image: simulator]

Comment: What version of the SDK and XCode are you working with?

Answer (score 0):

If you want this view controller to be limited to a certain orientation use in your view controller class

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

please read my answer here [Keep iPhone rotation in landscape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039182/keep-iphone-rotation-in-landscape/11039282#11039282)

Comment: @SJReddy this is actually a hack, but add this to your **viewDidLoad**, 

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(- 3.142 / 2);

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
     if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
            toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
          NSLog(@"Landscape Mode");
          // your code when your sdk is in landscape mode
    }
    else
    {
          NSLog(@"Portrait Mode");
          // your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: its a detail view loading on button action, i just created it, and in the nib, i went to the view to land scape in nib inspector, i did not write a single line of code

Answer (score 0):

How you design the view (portrait/landscape) in interface builder has no influence over how it will actually be shown. You need to set that in code (or possibly in a p-list).

Comment: in the plist i got land scape left and right items. and this method is like this

Comment: - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}